# Get data from 2 URLs in one component in React.js

Tags: reactjs, url

I need to place 2 independent URLs in one component. How to use them and where to place them to get the data of each of them?

```
    export default class App extends Component {
    async componentDidMount() {
            const response = await
                fetch(`URL_1`) 

            const user = await response.json();
```

}

Where and how to insert URL_2 ?

Comment: What do you mean with "place" ? Do you need to make 2 fetch requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a promise for the both hit the both urls simultaneously and upon resolution of both you can use it.

```
export default class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
            this.fetchData();
}

const fetchData = async() => {
  const requests = [];
  const responses = [];
  requests.push(fetch(`URL_1`));
  requests.push(fetch(`URL_2`));

  await Promise.all(requests).then(response => {
    response.forEach(resp => {
     responses.push(resp.data);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
     console.error(err);
  });
  return responses;
}
```